# UWP Is there a Container that will contain many other object and trim them if they go over Container

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I need a container (canvas?), that will contain many other object and trim them if they go over Container as below image.

It would be helpful if you could provide the source code.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [UIElement.Clip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.clip?view=winrt-22621) Property of Canvas, it can gets or set the `RectangleGeometry` used to define the outline of the contents of a UIElement.

```
   <Canvas Width="120" Height="120" Background="Gray">
        <Canvas.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,120,120"/>
        </Canvas.Clip>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Canvas.Left="-25" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.ZIndex="4" Height="50" Width="50" />
    </Canvas>
```